# JavaScript, calculate dynamic amount

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm new one here. Kindly please help me.
I have to calculate how much time I can buy if I use dynamic amount of money, so
in example: I can enter 5USD or 10USD etc;

I have some table:

```
15minutes -> cost 50 cents
1hour -> cost 3USD
2hours -> cost 6,10USD
3hours -> cost 9,30USD
4hours -> cost 12,30USD
5hours -> cost 15,30USD
6hours -> cost 18,30USD
7hours -> cost 21,30USD
8hours -> cost 24,30USD
```

So I need to calculcate in example how many hours and minutes I can by for 17 USD? please help me
best regards!

Comment: What code have you tried?  Can you only buy what's in the table, or can you buy, say, 16 minutes?

Comment: Above `3hours -> cost 9,30USD` it looks linear at 3 USD/hour

Comment: @Alex, no.  ie.. for 8 hours it's $24.3 which means it's 3.0375

Comment: First you shoud have the same units. Transform *hours* into *minutes* and *USD* into *cents*. This will make the math easier.

Comment: @g2000, above 3 hours they all end on .30, so it 3 USD/hour + 30 cent, still linear.

Comment: I believe the OP is buying phone cards, and he wants to use up all his money, and those are the only cards available.

Comment: 15 minutes for 50 cent is also by far the cheapest price per hour on this table, at $2/hour

Answer (score 1):

If you can only buy what's in the table,  you would need to loop

```
1) buy maximum amount without going over.
2) capture hours, and calculate money left.
3) repeat
```

This is assuming you are getting at least a better deal the larger the time you are buying.

so from 17USD, you would

```
 1) buy 1 card (15,30USD)
 2) 5 hours (total), (1,70USD left)
 1) buy 3 cards (3 x 0,50 = 1,50USD)
 2) 5 hours 45 min (total), (0,20 left)
 exit (not enough to buy lowest card

 Answer = 5 hours 45 min (0,20 left)
```

My assumption may appear flawed but here is a good reasoning.  Assuming these are phone cards, they typically have a set up charge (the first time), or base per-call charge each time you make a call, so you are not actually getting the full talk time stated on the card, only the balance amount.

They may say 5c/min but 10c base per-call charge, which means you get

```
- a 8 minute call on a "15minute" card for 50 cents, (6.25c/min)
- a 58 minute call on a "1hour" card for 300 cents (5.17c/min)
- a 484 minute call on a "8hours" card for 2430 cents (5.02c/min)
```

I know this may be more information than is needed for the answer, but the implementation depends on whether you are coding as a purchaser or a seller.  If you are the purchaser you have to do more math, and also provide inputs on what is the setup charge, per-call charge, and the number of calls you plan to make with each card.  This is why it is important for any phone plan to know your calling patterns.

Comment: Your assumption is actually wrong, `1h / 15min = 4`, `4 * 50cent = $2`, so buying in 15 minute intervals is the cheapest at $2/hour, `$17 / 50c * 15 min = 8h 30min`